# iOS objective-C, same memory address after releasing an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm learning objective-c manual memory management. I have the following example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSObject *o = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", o);
        [o release];
        NSLog(@"%@", o);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
2015-07-31 16:18:34.694 test[2378:96008] <NSObject: 0x10020d110>
2015-07-31 16:18:34.696 test[2378:96008] <NSObject: 0x10020d110>
```

How is it possible, that after calling 'release' object is still present in memory (has the same address as before calling 'release') and NSLog does NOT give me EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `o` still points to `0x10020d110`, even after you've released the object.

Releasing an object does not change references to that object to `nil`, but they are invalid and if you attempted to send a message via the reference, undefined behaviour would ensue.

In your case, however it does not crash, as both `NSLog()` calls are calling `[o description]`.

Comment: In this case, the memory was not overwritten yet, so `[o description]` could still pass.

Comment: So EXC_BAD_ACCESS will appear only if memory was already overwritten ?